# Getting error while creating the NodePort service in EKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to create Nodeport service in my EKS cluster however I am getting error as `for: "network/minikube/orderers/services.yaml": map: map[name:endpoint] does not contain declared merge key: port`. Can anybody help me to fix the issue.

My service.yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: orderer0-service
  labels: {
    component: orderer0,
    type: orderer
  }
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: endpoint
    - port: 7050
      targetPort: 7050
      nodePort: 30050
  selector:
    component: orderer0
    type: orderer
```

Answer (score 2):

`ports:` is representing list of ports, where by `-` you are separating the ports, (name, port, targetPort, nodePort) these four are combinedly representing one service port values, and you mistakenly included another list in (`- port: 7050`), your yaml should be like below,

```
  ports:
    - name: endpoint
      port: 7050
      targetPort: 7050
      nodePort: 30050
```

YAML:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: orderer0-service
  labels: {
    component: orderer0,
    type: orderer
  }
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: endpoint
      port: 7050
      targetPort: 7050
      nodePort: 30050
  selector:
    component: orderer0
    type: orderer
```

Answer (score 1):

The yaml has a problem.You don't need the `-` infront of `port`.It should be like below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: orderer0-service
  labels: {
    component: orderer0,
    type: orderer
  }
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: endpoint
      port: 7050
      targetPort: 7050
      nodePort: 30050
  selector:
    component: orderer0
    type: orderer
```